# Slicing a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I'm trying to learn to take advantage of all the benefits that slices offer.

The challenge task I created for myself was to create a slice for two dimensional array (even dimension) so that the lower right quadrant can be indexed from `0` instead of `len(matrix/2)`.

I wrote a code which implements this challenge (matrix dimension hardcoded to 4 for now - see question `2.`):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

// print matrix
// TODO: remove hardcoded dimension by accepting slice instead of array
func printMatrix(matrix [4][4]int) {
    fmt.Println("+", strings.Repeat("-", 2*len(matrix)-1), "+")
    for i := 0; i < len(matrix); i++ {
        fmt.Println("|", strings.Trim(strings.Join(strings.Fields(fmt.Sprint(matrix[i])), " "), "[]"), "|")
    }
    fmt.Println("+", strings.Repeat("-", 2*len(matrix)-1), "+")
}

const MatrixDim = 4

func main() {
    // init matrix
    matrix := [MatrixDim][MatrixDim]int{}

    // print matrix initial state
    printMatrix(matrix)

    // initialize lower right quadrant view
    matrixView := make([][]int, MatrixDim/2)
    for i := 0; i < MatrixDim/2; i++ {
        matrixView[i] = matrix[i+MatrixDim/2][MatrixDim/2:]
    }

    // modify lower right quadrant using the 0-indexed view
    matrixView[0][0] = 1
    matrixView[0][1] = 2
    matrixView[1][0] = 3
    matrixView[1][1] = 4

    // print modified matrix
    printMatrix(matrix)
}

/*
OUTPUT:
+ ------- +
| 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 |
+ ------- +
+ ------- +
| 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 0 0 |
| 0 0 1 2 |
| 0 0 3 4 |
+ ------- +
*/
```

1. I wonder if there is an easier and cleaner way to create 0-indexed view for lower right quadrant (without the initialization loop)
2. Speaking about good practices - I know that `printMatrix()` should accept `slice` or `array` pointer as parameter (instead of `array`). I wonder if it is better to define the `matrix` as `array` and pass its pointer/slice to `printMatrix()` or should I define it as a `slice` from the beginning?

Comment: 1. Not, that I am aware of.
2. Slices in Go are always passed by reference. There is no difference between array and slice, they are the same in go.

Comment: @VictorVieira array is different from slice in go. Array is a value type , has fixed length etc while slice is a reference type .  Most of the time you would be dealing with

Comment: @Sarath Sadasivan Pillai, yeah I know that. What I meant is they can be treated as the same thing since one is a concrete representation of another. It is the same thing to say that 1 is the same thing as an int. He doesn't need to make strict rules in his function to deal with array/slice. The only thing that is worth doing is if it brings benefits for knowing the exact value or array size. Otherwise don't need to be so restrictive